# Passing array through AJAX from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

I need to get an array generated from a script php. I have Latitude and Longitude for each user in a database.
I take the values from the db with this code (file.php):

```
$query = "SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM USERS";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$array=array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[]=$data['Latitude'];
    $array[]=$data['Longitude'];
}

echo $array;
```

and I call with ajax with this code:

```
$.post('./file.php',
     function( result ){    
         alert(result);
     });
```

but even if in the script php the array is correct (if I echo array[25] I obtain the right value) in Javascript I obtain "Undefined".
How can I get the array in correct way??
thanks!

edit: after encoded with json_encode($array); in php and JSON.parse(result) in javascript seems not working.
In the console I have the array, but I can't access to its values. (Array[0] gave me "undefined").

Comment: If your PHP script works correctly and outputs anything, you should not get `undefined` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use this

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

on server side

and

```
var arr=JSON.parse(result);
```

on client side

Comment: if I do arr[0] I get "undefined" even if, after parsing, the alert of result gave me the correct array

Comment: log into console received result and paste it here.

Comment: if I type arr in console I get: Array[1164]
[0 … 99]
0: "45.4655"
1: "9.18652"
2: "45.4655"
3: "9.18652"
4: "45.4655"
5: "9.18652"
6: "45.4655"
7: "9.18652"
8: "45.4655"
9: "9.18652"
10: "45.4655"  ecc. ecc.

Comment: @user1903898: Not sure, but looks like server returns array of array. `$array` on the server side is not what you think. Try to pass into client side some test data, e.g. `echo json_encode(array('item 0', 'item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'))`. And on the client side try to log `arr[0]`. If it works this way then you are looking for errors in wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

As Ruslan Polutsygan mentioned, you cen use

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

on the PHP Side.

On the Javascript-Side you can simply add the DataType to the $.post()-Function:

```
$.post(
  './file.php',
  function( result ){    
    console.log(result);
  },
  'json'
);
```

and the result-Parameter is the parsed JSON-Data.

You can also set the correct Content-Type in your PHP Script. Then jQuery should automaticly parse the JSON Data returned from your PHP Script:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

See
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
http://de3.php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the php array to json, try:

`echo json_encode($array);`

jQuery should be able to see it's json being returned and create a javascript object out of it automatically.

```
$.post('./file.php', function(result)
{    
     $.each(result, function()
     {
         console.log(this.Latitude + ":" + this.Longitude);
     });
});
```

Comment: Does jQuery parse for you?