# How to change SQL Search query based on the variable values received from the HTML filter form?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a form block which has search parameters in drop down, user selects at least one select options and clicks on `Search` button, which makes a form post to submit to JS script which gets values of all or some of select values and based on the select options, SQL query is modified.

But the problem is i need to make a combination of selection and modify manualy sql query to execute and retrive the result. But i want to do something in which SQL query automatically get modified based on the parameters it received.

Plz guide me.

Here is how my filter looks.

[image: Filter Section]

Below code of JS Script `loadtable.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var delay = 1000;

    // Campaign Submit Info
    $('[name="search_submit"]').click(function(e){              

              e.preventDefault();

              var lead_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_status_select option:selected').val();
              var campaign_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#campaign_status_select option:selected').val();
              var company_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#company_name_select option:selected').val();
              var tech_area = $('#filterformpost').find('#tech_area_select option:selected').val();
              var firm_size = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_size_select option:selected').val();
              var firm_type = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_type_select option:selected').val();
              var country_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#country_name_select option:selected').val();
              var state_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#state_name_select option:selected').val();
              var start_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#start_date_search').val();
              var end_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#end_date_search').val();

             $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",

                           url: "http://localhost/CRM/server/search.php",                        
                           data: {
                                    "lead_status":lead_status, 
                                    "campaign_status":campaign_status,
                                    "company_name":company_name,
                                    "tech_area":tech_area,
                                    "firm_size":firm_size,
                                    "firm_type":firm_type,
                                    "country_name":country_name,
                                    "state_name":state_name,
                                    "start_date":start_date,
                                    "end_date":end_date                          
                                  },
                           beforeSend: function() {
                             $('.message_box').html(
                             '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
                             );
                           }, 
                           success: function(data)
                           {
                           setTimeout(function() {
                           $('.message_box').html(data);
                           }, delay);
                           }                   

                         });








});
```

And PHP file in which i think there would be Search query `search.php`

```
<?php 

//SQL Search query


include('connection.php');

if ( ($_POST['lead_status']!="") ){


    $lead_status = $_POST['lead_status'];
    $campaign_status = $_POST['campaign_status'];


    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_main_lead_info`";

    $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   

      //here i get the select condition which i need to display over the html page using AJAX


}




}

?>
```

**Solution i am trying as below suggested:**

Part of section tag in `dashboard.html`

```
<!-- Filters -->

<div class="row">                
    <div class="col">
        <label><p><b>Select Filter</b></p></label>                    
    </div>          
</div>


<form action='' method='POST' class='filterformpost' id='filterformpost'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                    Lead Status:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                    <select id='lead_status_select'><option>Select</option>
                        <?php
                            echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";                                                
                            echo "<option value='Active'>Active Leads</option>";
                            echo "<option value='Paused'>Paused Leads</option>";
                            echo "<option value='Expired'>Expired Leads</option>";
                            echo "<option value='Unsubscribed'>Unsubscribed</option>";
                        ?>                            
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>                         
        </div>

        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                    Campaign Status:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                    <select id='campaign_status_select'><option>Select</option>
                        <?php     
                            echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";                                           
                            echo "<option value='Active'>Active</option>";
                            echo "<option value='Paused'>Paused</option>";
                            echo "<option value='Expired'>Expired</option>";
                            echo "<option value='Unsubscribed'>Unsubscribed</option>";
                        ?>                            
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>                        
        </div>

        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    Company Name:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-3">                                       

                        <?php                                            

                            include('./server/connection.php');

                            $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info ORDER By Company ASC";
                            $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                                                                                                                  
                            echo "<select id='company_name_select'>";
                            echo "<option>select</option>";    
                            echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";                                        
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                echo "<option value='$row[Company]'> $row[Company] </option>";
                            }
                            echo "</select>";

                        ?>                          

                </div>
            </div>                        
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                    State:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-4">                                       

                        <?php                                            

                            include('./server/connection.php');

                            $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_state_info ORDER By StateName ASC";
                            $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                           

                            $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          

                            echo "<select id='state_name_select' name='StateName'>";
                            echo "<option>select</option>";  
                            echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";                                          
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                echo "<option value='$row[StateName]'> $row[StateName] </option>";
                            }
                            echo "</select>";

                        ?>                          

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                    Country:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                    <?php 

                        include('./server/connection.php');

                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_country_info ORDER By CountryName ASC";
                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         

                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          

                        echo "<select id='country_name_select' name='CountryName'>";
                        echo "<option>select</option>";
                        echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<option value='$row[CountryName]'> $row[CountryName] </option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";

                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>                      
        </div>

        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    Firm Type:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                    <?php 

                        include('./server/connection.php');

                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_firm_type_info ORDER By FirmType_Value ASC";
                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                    

                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          

                        echo "<select id='firm_type_select' name='FirmType'>";
                        echo "<option>select</option>";
                        echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<option value='$row[FirmType_Value]'> $row[FirmType_Value] </option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";

                    ?>       
                </div>
            </div>                         
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                    Firm Size:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-4">

                    <?php 

                        include('./server/connection.php');

                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_firm_size_info ORDER By FirmSize_Id ASC";
                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         


                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          


                        echo "<select id='firm_size_select' name='FirmSize'>";
                        echo "<option>select</option>";
                        echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<option value='$row[FirmSize_Value]'> $row[FirmSize_Value] </option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";

                    ?>

                </div>
            </div> 

        </div>

        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    Tech Area:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                    <?php 

                        include('./server/connection.php');

                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_tech_area_info ORDER By TechAreaName ASC";
                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         


                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          


                        echo "<select id='tech_area_select' name='TechAreaName'>";
                        echo "<option>select</option>";
                        echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<option value='$row[TechAreaName]'> $row[TechAreaName] </option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";

                    ?> 
                </div>
            </div>                          
        </div>                

        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                    Start Date:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-3-of-4">                          
                        <?php 

                        echo "<input type='date' id='start_date_search' name='startdate'>";

                        ?>                                    
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                    End Date:
                </div>
                <div class="col span-3-of-4">                            
                        <?php 

                        echo "<input type='date' id='end_date_search' name='enddate'>";

                        ?>                                     
                </div>
            </div>                         
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">               

        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-3-of-4">

                </div>               
            </div> 
        </div>    
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-3-of-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input type="submit" name='search_submit' value="Search">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
        <label></label>                            
    </div>
    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
        <div class="message_box" style="margin-left: 60px;">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In file `search.php`

```
<?php 

    include('connection.php');

    $sqlFlag = 0;

    function queryDelimiter(){
        global $sqlFlag;
        if ($sqlFlag == 0){
            $sqlFlag = 1;
            return ' WHERE ';
        }else{
            return ' AND ';
        }
    }

    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info";

    if(isset($_POST['lead_status']) and strlen(trim($_POST['lead_status'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LeadStatus = '".$_POST['lead_status']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['company_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['company_name'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."Company = '".$_POST['company_name']."'";
    }       

    if(isset($_POST['tech_area']) and strlen(trim($_POST['tech_area'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."TechArea = '".$_POST['tech_area']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['firm_size']) and strlen(trim($_POST['firm_size'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."FirmSize = '".$_POST['firm_size']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['firm_type']) and strlen(trim($_POST['firm_type'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."FirmType = '".$_POST['firm_type']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['country_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['country_name'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."Country = '".$_POST['country_name']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['state_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['state_name'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."State = '".$_POST['state_name']."'";
    }

    // if(isset($_POST['start_date']) and strlen(trim($_POST['start_date'])) > 0){
    //     $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LastContactDate >='".$_POST['start_date']."'";
    // }

    // if(isset($_POST['end_date']) and strlen(trim($_POST['end_date'])) > 0){
    //     $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."NextContactDate <= '".$_POST['end_date']."'";
    // }

    // $selectSQL .= " ORDER BY campaign_name";

    $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);



    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

and `loadtable.js` file is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var delay = 1000;

    // Campaign Submit Info
    $('[name="search_submit"]').click(function(e){              

              e.preventDefault();

              var lead_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_status_select option:selected').val();
              var campaign_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#campaign_status_select option:selected').val();
              var company_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#company_name_select option:selected').val();
              var tech_area = $('#filterformpost').find('#tech_area_select option:selected').val();
              var firm_size = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_size_select option:selected').val();
              var firm_type = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_type_select option:selected').val();
              var country_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#country_name_select option:selected').val();
              var state_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#state_name_select option:selected').val();
              var start_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#start_date_search').val();
              var end_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#end_date_search').val();

              console.log(lead_status)
              console.log(campaign_status)
              console.log(company_name)
              console.log(tech_area)
              console.log(firm_size)
              console.log(firm_type)
              console.log(country_name)
              console.log(state_name)
              console.log(start_date)
              console.log(end_date)

             $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           // url: "https://tribalyze.com/CRM/server/login.php",
                           url: "server/search.php",                        
                           data: {
                                    "lead_status":lead_status, 
                                    "campaign_status":campaign_status,
                                    "company_name":company_name,
                                    "tech_area":tech_area,
                                    "firm_size":firm_size,
                                    "firm_type":firm_type,
                                    "country_name":country_name,
                                    "state_name":state_name,
                                    "start_date":start_date,
                                    "end_date":end_date                          
                                  },
                           beforeSend: function() {
                             $('.message_box').html(
                             '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
                             );
                           }, 
                           success: function(data)
                           {
                           setTimeout(function() {
                           $('.message_box').html(data);
                           }, delay);
                           }                   

                         });





            });

            $.post('./server/search.php', function(result){

                console.log('Hello Console');

                $.each(result, function(){

                    console.log(result);

                });

            });  

});
```

Comment: You want AND or OR search combinations in your SQL? And all the fields are part of one and the same table or the data is distributed in different tables?

Comment: so that means so many SQL queries under if else

Comment: No, the query would be one, the main question is how many database tables you are using.

Comment: @mitkosoft, all values are part of same table

Comment: @mitkosoft i am using single table in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to check is there any value passed for each variable and to construct your query dynamically:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$sqlFlag = 0;
function queryDelimiter(){
    global $sqlFlag;
    if ($sqlFlag == 0){
        $sqlFlag = 1;
        return ' WHERE ';
    }else{
        return ' AND ';
    }
}

$selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info";

if(isset($_POST['campaign_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['campaign_name'])) > 0){
    $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."campaign_name = '".$_POST['campaign_name']."'";
}

if(isset($_POST['lead_status']) and strlen(trim($_POST['lead_status'])) > 0){
    $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."lead_status = '".$_POST['lead_status']."'";
}

$selectSQL .= " ORDER BY campaign_name";
```

Comment: Thanks this if else will helps let me check

Comment: Also when i got the row based on select condition then how to send the rows to display the table in Dashboard.html

Comment: How can we use AJAX in php to display the result of search query?

Comment: @RINKUYADAV, this is totally different question. Your PHP script `search.php` has to produce a JSON from the SQL result which you need to pass it to your page.

`echo json_encode($sql_result)` will do the work, just prepare a proper array. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480857/passing-array-through-ajax-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: That was what i needed thanks for this link and above solution.

Comment: when this if else will return OR condition for WHERE in SQL

Comment: @RINKUYADAV, it might return either `AND` or `OR`, depending on your needs. If you need them both, then you have to modify the function's logic a bit.

Comment: I have using same code as above question but still it is not executing my dynamic sql query

Comment: Please make some edit over it i am not able to detect error by using `console.log()`

Comment: If you need `OR` instead of `AND`, just change it in the function's body and don't forget to put spaces before and after it in order to produce proper SQL query. Most probably you have an error in your SQL, so just put echo `$selectSQL; die();` in your PHP script and observe the returned query by adding `console.log(data)` in your success state.

Comment: still not getting i updated my code please see into this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205513/discussion-between-mitkosoft-and-rinku-yadav).